# How prevalent is the heiban pronunciation of 見方?

Tags: nouns, pitch-accent

It seems 見方 is another one of those words that have become heibanified, is that right? How acceptable or common is the heiban pronunciation (or as jogloran mentioned, 尾高型)? [In this small pool](https://forvo.com/word/%E8%A6%8B%E6%96%B9/#ja) of native pronunciations, we see a split right down the middle, with two people pronouncing it みかた{LHH}, two みかた{LHL}, and the last one doing both.

The crucial thing is, if the 平板/尾高型 pronunciation is more common, does it mean it is becoming more (or has always been) difficult to tell it apart from another word that possibly occurs more often, 味方?

Comment: NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 has yet another pitch accent listed, which is 尾高型.

Comment: @jogloran That's 標準語 too? Wow

Comment: The thing about your Forvo pronunciations is that since the word is pronounced in isolation, we can't distinguish 平板 from 尾高.

Comment: Yeah, I came to that realization as soon as I read your first comment. Let me reword my post a bit.

Comment: I don't think this is a case of recent *heibanification*. [みかた]【LHH】 sounds completely standard to me and that's how I have always pronounced it.

Comment: NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 lists only one pattern for [しかた](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典/exact/しかた), two for [みかた](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典/exact/みかた), and three for [でかた](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典/exact/でかた).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

見方 is traditionally and still dominantly pronounced 尾高, aka accented on the third (=last) mora, aka [3].

[3][2] has been the order suggested by dictionaries anywhere from NHK 1998 to NHK 2016, 新明解国語辞典 7th edition (2011), 大辞林 4th edition (2019).

It’s in *more* recent dictionary editions that we see the preference reversed to [2][3]: 新明解国語辞典 8th edition (2020), 大辞泉 (2021). But 三省堂国語辞典 8th edition (2021) keeps it with [3] preferred.

Personally I disagree with that reversal, as even most of the younger people I know say it [3] still. Certainly news casters and other voice professionals all still say it [3]. So this is what I would recommend to a learner.

With regards to confusion with 味方, it will sound different in most sentences because 味方 is [0], not [3]. And the meaning (and as a result contexts/collocations) are considerably different. I can’t recall ever being confused once.